# Computing RREF on matrix with variables in coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\pmatrix{a&a&-1&1\\ 1&-1&1&a\\ -1&1&a&1\\ }$

It says to consider cases such as a=0 or a does not equal 0.

Comment: What have you done so far? What is the definition of RREF?

Comment: I would say the same procedure as free variables.

Comment: I tried a = 0 and ended with this result : $\pmatrix{1&-1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1\\ }$

I know this is in RREF but I wasn't sure if I should try other cases or trying to get it as close to RREF with the variables in before substituting.

Answer (score 1):

$\pmatrix{a&a&-1&1\\ 1&-1&1&a\\ -1&1&a&1\\ }$

$\implies\pmatrix{1&1&-\frac1a&\frac1a\\ -1&1&-1&-a\\ -1&1&a&1\\ }$ by $R_1\to\frac1aR_1, R_2\to-R_2$

$\implies \pmatrix{1&1&-\frac1a&\frac1a\\ 0&2&-1-\frac1a&-a+\frac1a\\ 0&2&a-\frac1a&1+\frac1a\\ }$ by $R_2\to R_1+R_2,R_3\to R_1+R_3$

$\implies \pmatrix{1&1&-\frac1a&\frac1a\\ 0&1&-\frac12-\frac1{2a}&-\frac a2+\frac1{2a}\\ 0&-1&-\frac a2+\frac1{2a}&-\frac12-\frac1{2a}\\ }$ by $R_2\to\frac12R_2,R_3\to-\frac12R_3$

$\implies \pmatrix{1&1&-\frac1a&\frac1a\\ 0&1&-\frac12-\frac1{2a}&-\frac a2+\frac1{2a}\\ 0&0&-\frac 12-\frac a2&-\frac12-\frac a2\\ }$ by $R_3\to R_2+R_3$

$\implies \pmatrix{1&1&-\frac1a&\frac1a\\ 0&1&-\frac12-\frac1{2a}&-\frac a2+\frac1{2a}\\ 0&0&1&1\\ }$ by $R_3\to\frac1{-\frac12-\frac a2}R_3$

Back-substituting from here we get $x_3=1,x_2=-\frac{a^2-a-2}{2a},x_1=\frac{a^2-a+2}{2a}$. So the reduced row echelon form is

$$\pmatrix{1&0&0&\frac{a^2-a+2}{2a}\\0&1&0&-\frac{a^2-a-2}{2a}\\0&0&1&1}$$